# When set value of action, post/get don't work

Tags: php, forms, post, get, action

I have form:

```
echo "
<form action='http://domain.com/' method='get'>
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$_SESSION['shoppingcart_id']."' />
<input type='hidden' name='account_id' value='".$account_id."' />
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='add' />
<input type='submit' class='form-button' value='Buy' />
</form>
";
```

and `get` don't get any results.

```
http://domain.com/
```

If I set value of action to empty like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='' />
```

the result is:

```
http://domain.com/?order_id=xxxxxxxx&acount_id=xxxxxxxxx$action=
```

I'm confused why with empty action get results, but with action don't get anything!?

p.s. With "post" is the same.

Comment: check out what variables are being sent first. try web inspector/firebug in your browser, or on your receiving page, do a var_dump($_GET); die("Show variables"); or var_dump($_POST); die("Show variables"); and look at your results.

Comment: You should also avoid echoing HTML, for the record :) It's difficult to read, and more difficult to edit.

Comment: When set value of action result is nothing, but when set empty value result is: ["action"]=> string(0) and the values of varaibles.

Comment: Is order_id and account_id being sent, and are the values of them correct? To debug, try changing the name of the action input to something like qwerty1 and seeing if that's sent.

Comment: I turned off all javascripts and start working, now I'm looking for what script makes problems.